# prunsrv service with external properties file

Tags: java, procrun

I have a java .jar file I created using NetBeans.  I am using apaches procrun (prunsrv.exe) to install that .jar as a Windows Service.  I modified the code to get a property from a config.properties file.
I added the config.properties file to the same folder that my .jar file resides in.
My code is as follows:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream inputStream = MyService.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
props.load(inputStream);
```

On the last line of my code, I am getting a NPE when I attempt to start my service.  I assume this is because the file is not found.
I modified the manifest.mf as follows:

```
Class-Path: .
```

I also tried copying config.properties to the "lib" folder (subfolder to where my .jar file is located).  Same results.

I modified the "set PR_CLASSPATH" line in the batch file that installs the service as follows:

```
set PR_CLASSPATH=MyService.jar;.
```

Still same NPE.

How can I get my code to recognize my config.properties file once the service has been installed?

Thanks,
Raymond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use to load resources in these situations and seems to work most of the time:

```
public static InputStream getResourceAsStream(String path) {
    return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
}
```

Could you check, if this helps in your case?

Another strategy to overcome this problem is the one described in my comment:

"*copy the configuration file to a specific absolute folder path (i.e. c:\test) and change the classpath to point to that folder (set PR_CLASSPATH=MyService.jar;.;c:\test)*"

Comment: Same issue.  I passed "config.properties" to that method and the InputStream is still null.

Comment: Can you copy the copy the configuration file to a specific absolute folder path (i.e. c:\test) and change the classpath to point to that folder (set PR_CLASSPATH=MyService.jar;.;c:\test). And then retry?

Comment: That did it.  After I tried that and it worked, I simply created a "resources" folder under my root and added that to my CLASSPATH.  I believe my problem was the usage of the manifest.mf in conjuction with the "set PR_CLASSPATH" in my install.bat.  I removed Class Path entry in my manifest.mf and modified the PR_CLASSPATH to include all I needed.

Comment: So your problem seems to be solved now :) I have updated the question to include the comment which helped, so that you can mark the question as solved.